# Storing / recalling the value of a variable in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

Is there a way to store / recall values of a variable in Netlogo from previous ticks?

I need a way to recall what a variable was from previous ticks.  If my turtle variable R was equal to 0 the last 3 ticks, I need it to set another variable back to zero.

Here is what that I was thinking.

```
to regression
  ask turtles [if (R = 0 from last 3 ticks [Set Oin 0 ]]
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about making a list of variables, then limiting the length of that list to how far back you'd like the agent to "remember"

```
set memory []
```

then add to the list each tick and get rid of old memories with

```
  set memory lput value memory
if length memory >= 4 [set memory but-first memory]
```

and if zero is on the list, have that alter behavior in some way

```
if member? 0 memory  [blah]
```

Comment: Ahh, that just about did it.  I swapped out the `if member? 0 memory  [blah]` bit with `if memory = [0 0 0] [blah] ` but the idea of using a list works great.  Thanks for the help.